# How to call out sim in matlab function block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to run a PID controller (another model in simulink) using sim command in a matlab function block.
However it takes long iteration, seems to be that the matlab function block need more time.

How to get faster result?

Here is my code in matlab function block:

```
function [Kpp,Kii,Kdd] = fcn(u)

coder.extrinsic('sim');
sim('ExternePID'); %call out to ExternePID model
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that, that won't work. Instead include your second Simulink model as a [referenced model](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/overview-of-model-referencing.html) in your top-level Simulink model. This way, both models can run concurrently.

Comment: Thank you @am304 for the answer..but i don't really understand..include the model as referenced in top-level?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the link provided for an overview of model referencing, you'll get the idea. Basically, it's a way to encapsulate a model within another model.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply..I'll try to get a good understanding on the referenced model first..but is it also applicable if I program a loop in the first model to call out the second model (The PID control model) in each iteration within one population size.